# i am trying to make a new component inside a js variable

Tags: reactjs, components

i am trying to make a new component inside a js variable. this is my code

```
class CourseSales extends Component {
    render(){
        var Course = this.props.items.map((item,i) => {
            return <Course name={item.name} price={item.price} key={i}/>
        });
       return(
           <div>
               <h1>Purchase your fav. course</h1>
               <p>{this.Course}</p>
           </div>
      );
   }
}
```

but its not showing result in the course component and console is giving me this error

```
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Comment: just change `{this.Course}` to `{Course}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.Course` is undefined. Assigning a value to `var Course` does not automatically assign that value to `this.Course`. Saving the array to `Course` is not necessary. I would recommend the following:

```
class CourseSales extends Component {
    render(){
      return(
          <div>
              <h1>Purchase your fav. course</h1>
                {this.props.items.map((item,i) => (
                  <p key={i}>
                    <Course name={item.name} price={item.price} />
                  </p>
                )}
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to make a variable which return a componet and like course and want to call it in coursesales component

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand @vivekmodi. The above code will work a variable is not needed.

Comment: i got my mistake i just have to use course instead of this.course and i have to change the name of variable because i am making a component with same name thank you